# look up variants of a URL in a mysql database field

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a MYSQL query which counts the number of times www.google.com appears in a database field, which works fine, what I am trying to find is a way that it will identify Google, whether it is www.google.com, www.google.co.uk, etc, etc

Below is my code,

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE referer='www.google.com' and  member ='$site_id'");
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: **DING!** SQL INJECTION ALERT ON `member = '$site_id'`! **DING DING!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a simple `LIKE` query:

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE referer LIKE 'www.google.%' and  member ='$site_id'`

This will match on any value of `referer` that starts with the string "www.google.".

Also, the mandatory suggestion that you not use the `mysql_*` functions... which are being deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: Perfect thank you, didn't realise it was as simple as that and thanks for the advice.  Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LIKE` to search a string with wildcard syntax: `%` for zero or more of any character:

```
WHERE referer LIKE 'www.google.co%'
```

You can make that search more specific or less as well.

---

By the way your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: @YounElan there is a vulnerability in the query regardless of whether the input is sanitized